# Cloudflare IP not near my place

Tags: cdn, cloudflare

could you please help me understand why am I getting Phoenix IP address when I ping [my service](https://api.abalin.net)? This site is fully behind Cloudflare CDN so I would expect it will serve me nearest datacenter which is Prague, Europe. Not Phoenix.

Ip I´m getting http://www.ip2location.com/104.31.80.242

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an anycast address from CloudFlare, you can see it as CDN in the usage type in IP2Location. The exact server location depends to your own location. You could not use a geolocation database to detect the server location because there are many servers sharing the same IP address.

You can try to ping the IP address. If it is less than 50ms latency, then it should be very good.

Comment: Thank you Michael! Makes perfect sense.